# How to count the number of rows which have same starting letters in Oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table Customers:

```
╔════════════╦═════╗
║ CustomerID ║ ... ║
╠════════════╬═════╣
║ ACC20011   ║ ... ║
║ ACC30122   ║ ... ║
║ ACC12356   ║ ... ║
║ EVG12345   ║ ... ║
║ DAA23445   ║ ... ║
║ DAA23548   ║ ... ║
╚════════════╩═════╝
```

I need the following output:

```
╔════════════╦═══════╗
║ CustomerID ║ Count ║
╠════════════╬═══════╣
║    Acc     ║  3    ║
║    EVG     ║  1    ║
║    DAA     ║  2    ║
╚════════════╩═══════╝
```

I wrote the following query. But I know its wrong. Kindly correct me.

```
select CustomerID , count(*) as Count 
from Customers
where CustomerID is like 'ACC%'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(CustomerID, 1, 3) AS CustomerID, COUNT(*)
FROM Customers
GROUP BY SUBSTR(CustomerID, 1, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

The below query will also work if u have data format like `'A1234','ABCC2'` etc

```
  SELECT substr(CustomerID, 1, regexp_instr(CustomerID, '\d+') - 1) AS string
        ,count(*) as cnt
    FROM customer
    GROUP BY substr(CustomerID, 1, regexp_instr(CustomerID, '\d+') - 1)
```

**Edit**
Another way to do the above in is with the use of `regexp_replace`

```
select regexp_replace(CustomerID,'\d+','') as string,count(*) cnt from customer
group by regexp_replace(CustomerID,'\d+','')
```

Above one replace all the digits present in your customerid.

Comment: Thank u. It is very nice idea and can be used in all cases :)

Comment: @user5505661 your welcome. Yes you can use it in several cases.